# HTML5 Datetime-Local picker unable to alter default value

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

Im using the HTML5 datetime-local picker and have some custom JS to set the default date/time for me however when trying to use the picker to change the date or time, it doesn't update the input that contains the original value from JS.

Any ideas?

HTML:

```html
<input id="dt" class="input" type="datetime-local">
```

JS:

```js
  let dateTime = new Date().toISOString();
  dateTime = dateTime.split(".")[0];
  document.getElementById("dt").value = dateTime;
```

TIA

Comment: What browser are you using? that `type` doesn't work everywhere. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#browser_compatibility) (I'm not sure what the effects are in an unsupported browser)

Comment: Im using Chrome - latest version I believe. The DatePicker itself works perfectly if the JS code didn't insert a default value. But when I include the JS, it doesn't update the input value...

Comment: The example is a little confusing as it gets the UTC date and time, then presents it as local. Also, assigning to the value property doesn’t update the default value.  Either assign to *defaultValue* or use `setAttribute(‘value’, time stamp)` (I think, can’t check right now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems to be a little bug when by default JS inserted 'seconds' into the datetime-picker.

By removing the seconds from new Date().toISOString() it has now allowed me to freely use the picker to set the date/time and it will update the value.

```js
  let dateTime = new Date().toISOString();
  dateTime = dateTime.split(".")[0];
  dateTime = dateTime.slice(0, -3);
  document.getElementById("dt").value = dateTime;
```

Comment: You don’t need both *slice* and *split*, *toISOString* has a specified format so `toISOString.slice(0,16)` is sufficient. :-)

Comment: ^ Best answer I could find 
`value={isoVariableString.slice(0, 16)}`